# Read blob data that comes from asp.net core to Angular 7

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, filesaver.js

Good day. Please help me with my problem, I was not able to read properly the data that comes from backend to my angular. What im doing here is downloading a file that comes from the backend(asp.net core)

This is the code for my controller

```
[HttpPost("Document")]
public HttpResponseMessage Document()
        {
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files;

                var fileData = _documentToPdf.DocumentToPdf(file[0].OpenReadStream());
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;


                response = new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileData.ToArray())
                };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "pdf.pdf";
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileData.Length;

                Console.WriteLine("file data size: " + fileData.Length);


                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And this is my angular code

```
uploadAndProgress(files: File[]){
    console.log(files)
    var formData = new FormData();
    Array.from(files).forEach(f => formData.append('file',f))

    this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/DocumentToPdf/Document', formData, {reportProgress: true, responseType: 'blob',  observe: 'events'})
      .subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          this.percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this.uploadSuccess = true;
          console.log('Success');
          console.log('event: ' + event);
          this.downloadFile(event, 'download.pdf');
        }
    });
  }

  downloadFile(data: any, filename: string) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
    console.log(blob);
    saveAs(blob, filename);
  }
```

The code `Console.WriteLine("file data size: " + fileData.Length);` returns a `65651` but the code in angular which is console.log(blob); it returns

```
size: 15
type: "application/octet-stream"
```

So why is it that they are not the same? So how to i properly read the blob that comes from asp.net to my angular so i can download it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

In your service

```
url: string = "some url";

getBlob(): Observable<Blob> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'      
    });
    return this.httpClient.get<Blob>(this.url, {headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' });
  }
```

Then in your component

```
imageBlobUrl: string = null;

getImage() : void {
    this.blobService.getBlob()
      .subscribe((val) => {
          this.createImageFromBlob(val);
        });
  }
  createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      this.imageBlobUrl = reader.result;
    }, false);
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
```

Then in your view

```
  <img [src]="imageBlobUrl">
```

Comment: Where does blobService came from? Thank you

Comment: Is the name of the service to get the blob :)

Comment: follow up question sir. I need to pass the file as paramater. So how can i pass it?

this.http.get<Blob>(this.url, formData, {headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }); but the get method only accept 1-2 parameter. I need to pass the file to be process. Thank you for your time